# Word Macro - set orientation of selected page

Tags: vba, ms-word, orientation

I'm trying to make a macro where users can select a table within a document and switch the orientation of the specific page it's on to landscape. I've tried both recording doing the action and writing the macro myself but it never seems to work properly. This is as close as I've gotten but it makes the page the table is on and everything before it landscape.

```
Sub TableLandscape()
'
' TableLandscape Macro
'
'
    'Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    'Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
    'ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.Start, End:=Selection.Start).Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

    'Selection.InsertBreak _
         Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Selection.Start = Selection.Start + 1

    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.End, End:=Selection.End).InsertBreak _
         Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage

    With Selection.PageSetup
        .LineNumbering.Active = False
        .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .Gutter = InchesToPoints(0)
        .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .FooterDistance = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .PageWidth = InchesToPoints(11)
        .PageHeight = InchesToPoints(8.5)
        .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
        .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
        .SectionStart = wdSectionContinuous
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
        .SuppressEndnotes = False
        .MirrorMargins = False
        .TwoPagesOnOne = False
        .BookFoldPrinting = False
        .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
        .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
        .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
    End With

    'ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.End, End:=Selection.End).InsertBreak _
         'Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know a solution for you, but per [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.pagesetup) it seems possible using the [sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.sections) object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do that:

```
Sub RotatePage()
    Dim TableRange As Range, TableStart As Range, TableEnd As Range
    Set TableRange = Selection.Tables(1).Range
    Set TableStart = TableRange.Duplicate
    With TableStart
        .SetRange Start:=TableStart.Start - 1, End:=TableStart.End
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    End With
    Set TableEnd = TableRange.Duplicate
    With TableEnd
        .SetRange Start:=TableEnd.Start, End:=TableEnd.End + 1
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    End With
    TableRange.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
End Sub
```